# Get PID in bash file with open screen

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, pid

I am a beginner in bash programming. I want to obtain PIDs from processes, in order to use `trap` and `kill` to receive and send signals to a program in the same file.

In particular, I start the program opening a screen in this way:

```
screen -d -m  "start program"
process_id=`/bin/ps -fu $USER| grep "program" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}'`
```

The variable `process_id` contains two PIDs, not one. If I run without a screen, I don't have this issue (anyway, I have to open the screen).

Does anyone have solutions to this problem?

---

Another question: If I write

```
screen -d -m  "start program">log
```

the log file isn't printed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, [`pgrep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep)(or *process grep*) is what you are looking for.

For instance, the following will return a list of PIDs of all *bash* processes running.

```
preg bash
```

And if you read the docs:

> -signal
> Defines the signal to send to each matched process. Either the numeric or the symbolic signal name can be used.

---

Second question, you could either use the `-LogFile` flag if your version of `screen` supports it. Or specify the log file in your `.screenrc` configuration file.

[This has already been answered](https://serverfault.com/questions/248193/specifying-a-log-name-for-screen-output-without-relying-on-screenrc).

---

#### *Edit:*

If you can't access the user's home directory where the configuration file `.screenrc` is usually put, you could change the `$SCREENRC` environment variable to explicitly set to an alternative path for it.

Comment: Dear Ayman, thank you very much. I solved the first problem. For the second question: my version doesn't support "-LogFile"; I can't modify .screenrc because I am using an external server and I don't have the permissions. Is there another way to print log files, please? Thank you!

Comment: @Byba, If you can't access the user home directory, you could change the `$SCREENRC` environment variable to explicitly set to an alternative `.screenrc` config file.  You are welcome :)

Comment: @Byba, Glad to help :) I have added that part to the answer.